# Inheritance and smart pointers (std::shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, virtual-functions

There are a lot of things that needs to be said. First off, I would like to know if the approach below is considered a design pattern or even a common technique (That's why I didnt provide further information on the title). If thats the case, whats the name?
Anyways, this is a minified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Since I need to use copying, I found that using std::shared_ptr is the best to avoid deallocated (deleted) pointers.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : ptr(nullptr) {}
    Foo(const Foo& foo) : ptr(foo.ptr) {}
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    void whatever() {
        if (ptr)
            ptr->whateverHandler();
    }

    void reset() {
        ptr.reset();
    }

    void resetBar() {
        ptr.reset(new Bar);
    }

    // Other resets here...

protected:
    Foo(Foo* foo) : ptr(foo) {}

private:
    // Every child class should override this
    virtual void whateverHandler() {
        throw "whateverHandler cant be called within base class";
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar() : Foo(this) {}
    void whateverHandler() {
        printf("Bar's handler!!! \n");
    }
};
```

This all looks good and compiles fine, however, the following exame crashes. Why is that?

```
int main()
{
    {
        Foo f;

        f.resetBar();
    }

    return getchar();
}
```

Comment: When a `Bar` is destroyed, its `Foo` is destroyed twice

Comment: You may need `std::enable_shared_from_this`. However, in this particular example, you don't need it, either

Comment: You're also missing the virtual destructor.

Comment: @Danh That's exactly whats happening! Why is that?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Bar() : Foo(this) {}
```

Be careful when you pass `this` to a `shared_ptr`.

Think about what will happen after`f.resetBar();` and `ptr.reset(new Bar);` again.

1. For `new Bar`, an object of type `Bar` will be constructed, and inside its constructor `this` is passed to the parent class member `ptr`, then the object is managed by the it which is a `std::shared_ptr`.
2. After that, the object is managed by `f.ptr`; which is another `std::shared_ptr`.

So there're two `std::shared_ptr`s pointing to the same object, but `std::shared_ptr`s don't know anything about that; because you're constructing them separately. When `f` and `f.ptr` is destroyed, the pointed-to object will be destroyed too. Then the member `ptr` will be destroyed, it will try to destroyed the same object again, which leads to UB.

I'm not sure about what the design trying to accomplish, but just stopping passing `this` to a `std::shared_ptr` could eliminate UB.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    void whatever() {
        if (ptr)
            ptr->whateverHandler();
    }
    void reset() {
        ptr.reset();
    }
    void resetBar() {
        ptr.reset(new Bar);
    }
    // Other resets here...
private:
    // Every child class should override this
    virtual void whateverHandler() = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void whateverHandler() {
        printf("Bar's handler!!! \n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Foo f;
        f.resetBar();
        f.whatever();
        f.resetSthElse();
        f.whatever();
    }
}
```

And IMO, having a member of type `std::shared_ptr` pointing to derived class is confusing; separating it might be better. And then, I think it might be the [bridge design partern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void whatever() {
        if (ptr)
            ptr->whateverHandler();
    }
    void reset() {
        ptr.reset();
    }
    void resetBar() {
        ptr.reset(new BarHandler);
    }
    // Other resets here...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<FooHandler> ptr;
};

class FooHandler
{
public:
    virtual ~FooHandler() = default;
    // Every child class should override this
    virtual void whateverHandler() = 0;
};

class BarHandler : public FooHandler
{
public:
    void whateverHandler() {
        printf("Bar's handler!!! \n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Foo f;
        f.resetBar();
        f.whatever();
        f.resetSthElse();
        f.whatever();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've slightly changed my post to match the real problem (the old one was kind of wrongly stated and you answered it). Why does `d.resetFree()` crash, though?

Comment: @YvesHenri Nothing changed. For `f.resetBar();` and `ptr.reset(new Bar);`, `f.ptr` will point to the constructed object, which is pointed by its own parent member `ptr` too. Note there're two object of type `Foo` and `Bar`, both's member `ptr` point to the same object.

Comment: How can I achieve what I'm looking for, then? The reason I chosed smart pointers is because I need to pass the base's internal pointer around on copies but then I need to safely detect whether it was deleted or not. Just change it for a raw pointer and do the deallocations and you'll have the old version (that I tried). To be clear, imagine you have 2 Bars declared, but one was made through copy constructor  (retrieves internal pointer) but then you destroy the copied Bar  (eg. out of scope). Now the copy will crash on the next `whatever` call! :(

Comment: @YvesHenri I'm not sure what this design is trying to accomplish; 
At least, stop passing `this` will get rid of the error. `ptr.reset(new Bar);` means the constructed `Bar` has been managed by one `std::shared_ptr`, it's unnecessary to add another one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The idea here is to use `whatever` **within the base class OR any of its childs (inheritance), being mainly by the base class**. The base class should be able to "transform" itself in one of its childs through the reset functions and the same for the childs (base to any of its childs and any childs into another child). Calling different `whatever` logics through child classes is easy through virtual functions, but what if its a base class call? Was I clear? Hope you have understand! I really appreciate the help! Your answer has also been accepted btw.

Comment: @YvesHenri I'm not sure I've understood. :) Anyway, I tried. See edited answer.

Comment: Perfect! That really did the trick! You deserved an upvote! :)
 If you're curious, take a look at what I've been trying to accomplish (I know, there's a std::function already, but it doesnt fit in my case): https://github.com/YvesHenri/Delegator
I'll appreciate any criticism on the code (you can do that anywhere on the git repo)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133825/discussion-between-yves-henri-and-songyuanyao).

Answer (score 0):

The `Foo::ptr` holds a pointer to its mother `Foo(this)` with reference count 1.

In `Foo::resetBar()`, when **Foo** asking **Foo::ptr** to call `reset(new Bar)`, **Foo::ptr** gave up its ownership to its mother **Foo**`(this)` and found out the reference count was already decreased to 0, so it need to kill **Foo**.

When the `Foo` is dead, its children are killed. So **Foo::ptr** must be dead, too. Then assigning the `new Bar` to dead `Foo::ptr` causes UB.